# How to find all files of a file-type recursively, not based off extension(s) on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find all files of a certain file-type within a certain directory using a bash script, and outputting the results to a text file.

I've tried using the "find" command, but that only uses file names, not types.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "mp3 files:" > ~/Desktop/prohibitedfiles.txt
find / -name '*.mp3' >> ~/Desktop/prohibitedfiles.txt
echo -e "\nmov files:" >> ~/Desktop/prohibitedfiles.txt
find / -name '*.mov' >> ~/Desktop/prohibitedfiles.txt
echo -e "\nmp4 files:" >> ~/Desktop/prohibitedfiles.txt
find / -name '*.mp4' >> ~/Desktop/prohibitedfiles.txt
```

The code will output all files that end with .mp3, .mov, and .mp4. It will not output files that are mp3 files that do not include .mp3 in the filename. Is there any way to list files of a file-type, not relying on extensions?

Comment: Files don't really have types, at least not in the sense of a tag that specifies the contents of a file. Files are just collections of bytes, and the only way to determine the type is to examine the contents directly (like the `file` command does).

Comment: The command `file --mime-type -b <file-name>` can be used to try and sniff out the mime type of a file.

Comment: you may filter out text files easily.

Comment: I'm not trying to find the file type of something, I need to find all files of a file-type.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802914/bash-script-for-finding-files-by-mime-type), second answer seems more efficient

Comment: You'll need to scan every file on your system. Prepare to let you script run for a long time.

Comment: It worked using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802914/bash-script-for-finding-files-by-mime-type) 
    "sudo find /home -print | file -if - | grep -i "jpeg" | cut -d: -f1"